# HttpClient to Httpurlconnection conversion

Tags: java, android, http, httpclient, httpurlconnection

I've been using httpclient in my previous apps and they worked like charm. however as httpclient is now depricated in latest android builds can you help me with this particular piece of code? I've tried a lot to convert this into httpurlconnection it simply doesnt work for me...

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

// Creating HTTP Post

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(link);

//Name value pair created what you want to send to server

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Languages",lang));

nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("voice",vc));

nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ex","execute"));

nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("op",text));

nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("count",count));

nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("speed",speed));

//httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, "UTF-8")); // UTF 8 added to send indic string to server

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

final int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

Log.d("Response Status Code",String.valueOf(statusCode));

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block

e.printStackTrace();

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block

e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block

e.printStackTrace();

}
```

and this is what i have coded for the httpurlconnection:

```
URL url = new URL(link);

urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

Map<String, String> param = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
param.put("Languages", lang);

param.put("voice",vc);
param.put("ex","execute");

param.put("op",nt);
param.put("count",count);
param.put("speed",speed);

StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String,String> param1 : param .entrySet()) {
if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param1.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
postData.append('=');
postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param1.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
}
byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
int postDataLength = postDataBytes.length;

urlConnection.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
urlConnection.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
Log.d("getoutputstream", postDataBytes.toString());

InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
// readStream(in);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
str = br.readLine();

Log.d("output of str",str);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tell us what 'simply doesn't work' means.

Comment: In httpclient method i was sending those data to the server which would convert text to speech and in return i used to get an audio file of that converted text. In httpurlconnection method the data is being sent but the audio file which i receive in return is blank, i'm guessing the data sent isn't right. any suggestions?